# winuser.h defines not declared with MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

Im trying to use [SetWinEventHook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx), however when I try to compile with MinGW it says that [SetWinEventHook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx) as well as some other definitions and functions are 'not declared in this scope'.

I've googled alot and found that I need to define the windows version. I've tried that, but it didn't help.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x510
#define WINVER 0x0510
```

I've also tried to set the compiler flags.

```
-D_WIN32_WINDOWS=0x0510
```

But that didn't help either. I got it compiling using Visual Studio, but with MinGW it just won't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Pretty typical mingw problem, use the MinGW-w64 project instead.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Installing MinGW-w64 helped, thanks. To be able to compile 32bit with it, just select to install the "sjlj"-version from the installer. Then use the compiler flag "-m32".